# What does a period signify in lua?

Tags: lua

I have some proprietary implementation of lua, and all the variables exposed to me are in the form of 'ME.AV123' (for example). What is 'ME'? Is it a namespace? Is it a class? Is there a way to tell? Should I be able to do some sort of `type(ME)` (which does not seem to work)? In the documentation it says `the keyword 'ME' is used to access the objects in the local database.`

Follow-up, bonus question - Is there a way to get to all the variables in ME? I.e. - like the global variables use _G[varname], is there an equivalent way to do this for ME?

I apologize if I am not giving you enough. I am new to Lua, and I have relatively limited functionality through this .... thing.

Just to maybe put a finer point on it, and illustrate what I am actually trying to do:

I can interact with some set of variables, which are all in the documentation. All of them are name(addressed?) 'ME.varname'. So, to set 'AV120' to '1', I would say `ME.AV120 = 1`. I need to set some.. few dozen of these things, and would like a way to loop through all the  variables, setting them as I go. I would think something like:

```
for i,j in pairs(mySettingsTable) do 
    ME[i] = j 
end
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: You say type(ME) "does not seem to work". What happens exactly when you try that?

Comment: `ME` could be a table and `ME.AV123` could be a key of this. `type(ME)` would clarify this.

Comment: ME is a userdata.  `ME.varname` is the same as `ME["varname"]`, and your approach should work: `for k,v in pairs{AV120=1, AV123=0} do ME[k] = v end`

Comment: There is no way to get to all the variables inside ME.

Answer (score 2):

From the Lua reference manual:

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1

> The language supports this representation by providing a.name as
>   syntactic sugar for a["name"].

So ME.AV123 is the same as ME["AV123"].

It is just a more convenient form of indexing.

`type()` returns a string, in case you're wondering why the function does nothing on it's own. `print(type(ME))` should work.